# Alterar "createTextNode" para inserir em HTML?

Tags: javascript

tudo bem? Estou com uma certa dúvida, pois estou tentando criar um sistema bem simples de BBCode, mas por questões de visual, não estou usando um *textarea* normal. Estou usando uma *div* com o atributo **content editable** para poder editar o texto, mas a dúvida é: como faço para inserir HTML, pois no caso, ele funciona tudo certinho, mas insere tudo em texto plano :/

Alguma saída?

Eu achei este exemplo na web, mas não consegui fazer com quê ele saísse em HTML >:o

```js
function surroundSelection(textBefore, textAfter) {
    if (window.getSelection) {
        var sel = window.getSelection();
        if (sel.rangeCount > 0) {
            var range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
            var startNode = range.startContainer, startOffset = range.startOffset;
            var boundaryRange = range.cloneRange();
   
            var startTextNode = document.createTextNode(textBefore);
            var endTextNode = document.createTextNode(textAfter);
   
            boundaryRange.collapse(false);
            boundaryRange.insertNode(endTextNode);
            boundaryRange.setStart(startNode, startOffset);
            boundaryRange.collapse(true);
            boundaryRange.insertNode(startTextNode);
            
            // Reselect the original text
            range.setStartAfter(startTextNode);
            range.setEndBefore(endTextNode);
            sel.removeAllRanges();
            sel.addRange(range);
        }
    }
}

function surroundSelectionInBbcode(tagName) {
    surroundSelection("<span class='code'>[" + tagName + "]</span>", "<span class='code'>[/" + tagName + "]</span>");
}

document.getElementById("bold").onclick = function() {
    document.getElementById("pseudo_form").focus();
    surroundSelectionInBbcode("b");
    return false;
};
```

```css
*{font-family: arial;}
#pseudo_form, #pseudo_form_ok
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 30vh;
    padding: 10px;
    background: #222;
    color: #e5e5e5;
    display: block;
    margin: 5px;
    font-family: courier new;
 }
 .code 
 {
    color: red;
 }
```

```html
<button type="button" id="bold" value="b" unselectable="on">NEGRITO</button> (<<< selecione o texto e clique)

<div id="pseudo_form" contenteditable="true">
    meu texto
</div>

<HR>

<strong>EXEMPLO:</strong> Eu gostaria que ao clicar no botão "negrito", ficasse assim:

<div id="pseudo_form_ok">
    <span class='code'>[b]</span>meu texto<span class='code'>[/b]</span>
</div>
```

Quem puder me dar uma luz, agradeço imensamente desde já :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode fazer um `.replace` nos `&lt;` e nos `&gt;` que são as entidades que representam os símbolos `<` e `>` respectivamente:

```js
function surroundSelection(textBefore, textAfter) {
    if (window.getSelection) {
        var sel = window.getSelection();
        if (sel.rangeCount > 0) {
            var range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
            var startNode = range.startContainer, startOffset = range.startOffset;
            var boundaryRange = range.cloneRange();
   
            var startTextNode = document.createTextNode(textBefore);
            var endTextNode = document.createTextNode(textAfter);
   
            boundaryRange.collapse(false);
            boundaryRange.insertNode(endTextNode);
            boundaryRange.setStart(startNode, startOffset);
            boundaryRange.collapse(true);
            boundaryRange.insertNode(startTextNode);
            
            
            // Reselect the original text
            range.setStartAfter(startTextNode);
            range.setEndBefore(endTextNode);
            sel.removeAllRanges();
            sel.addRange(range);

            // REPLACE AQUI
            var texto = document.getElementById("pseudo_form").textContent;
            document.getElementById("pseudo_form").innerHTML = texto.replace(/&lt;/g,"<").replace(/&gt;/g,">");
        }
    }
}

function surroundSelectionInBbcode(tagName) {
    surroundSelection("<span class='code'>[" + tagName + "]</span>", "<span class='code'>[/" + tagName + "]</span>");
}

document.getElementById("bold").onclick = function() {
    document.getElementById("pseudo_form").focus();
    surroundSelectionInBbcode("b");
    return false;
};
```

```css
*{font-family: arial;}
#pseudo_form, #pseudo_form_ok
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 30vh;
    padding: 10px;
    background: #222;
    color: #e5e5e5;
    display: block;
    margin: 5px;
    font-family: courier new;
 }
 .code 
 {
    color: red;
 }
```

```html
<button type="button" id="bold" value="b" unselectable="on">NEGRITO</button> (<<< selecione o texto e clique)

<div id="pseudo_form" contenteditable="true">
    meu texto
</div>

<HR>

<strong>EXEMPLO:</strong> Eu gostaria que ao clicar no botão "negrito", ficasse assim:

<div id="pseudo_form_ok">
    <span class='code'>[b]</span>meu texto<span class='code'>[/b]</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Nossa, cara hahaha você salvou o pelotão inteiro. Nem tinha me mancado de faze _replace_. Agradeço de coração mesmo a ajuda. irei estudar o código pra ver se arrumo alguns bugs que encontrei de toda linha ficar colorida (mas isso aí já é comigo hahhaa)

Um abraço ,colega!